# Issue with Android's GoogleMap.CancelableCallback()

Tags: android, google-maps

Given the following code:

```
 System.out.println("begin");     
 LatLng me=new LatLng(myLat,myLongt);
 MainActivity.this.googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(me, 15), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            System.out.println("onFinish");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }
    });
```

The `onFinish()` method is called not when the animation is finished, instead, it's called really close to the time in which the animation fires.

```
05-24 19:54:26.025  23172-23172/com.bbb.gps I/System.out﹕ begin
05-24 19:54:26.140  23172-23172/com.bbb.gps I/System.out﹕ onfinish
```

The animation is taking ~1.5 seconds, so, there is a problem here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement delay for animate camera like below:

```js
MainActivity.this.googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(me, 15), 1500, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback()
```

Also,

```js
return true;
```

It will make sure that the events are consumed.

Comment: return true at where?