# GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() onFinish() is called before the animation finish

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a google map screen in Android. I want to move and zoom the camera to a location and get the boundary and zoom level after the animation complete.

This is what I have

```kotlin
        val location = LatLng(33.7701, -118.1937)
        val DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL = 13F
        googleMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL),
            object: GoogleMap.CancelableCallback{
                override fun onFinish() {
                    val visibleRegion = googleMap.projection.visibleRegion

                    Timber.i("zoom level is ${googleMap.cameraPosition.zoom}")
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Timber.i("Animate Camera Canceled")
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Most of the time it is working well. onFinish() timber log zoom level is 13.0

But occasionally, onFinish() timber log zoom level is 2.0
This means the animation haven't been completed and the map is not yet zoom in.

I have tried a suggestion from [Issue with Android's GoogleMap.CancelableCallback()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426049/issue-with-androids-googlemap-cancelablecallback)
However, setting the durationMs parameter only slow down the animation, it doesn't make sure onFinish() is call after the animation is complete.

Why is this happen? Is this a bug in google map Android?

I am using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1` referencing https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback)

Comment: Update this is indeed a bug in Android Google Map SDK https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200513914?pli=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway you can use workaround: move camera to target position in `onFinish()` via [`moveCamera()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)) call and then get projection:

```
...
override fun onFinish() {
    googleMap.moveCamera(<YOUR_DESIRED_TARGET_POSITION_AND_ZOOM>)
    val visibleRegion = googleMap.projection.visibleRegion
    Timber.i("zoom level is ${googleMap.cameraPosition.zoom}")
}
...
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. But I am more interested in find out why the callback is sometime called before the animation is over. If the callback is called before the animation complete, the visibleRegion inside onFinish() could still be the region before the animation, and therefore still the same problem

Comment: @BabyishTank You're welcome! `moveCamera()` stops any animation immediately, so, after `moveCamera()` the visibleRegion should be correct.